# Execute (part of) try block after except block

Tags: python, exception

I know that is a weird question, and probably there is not an answer.
I'm trying to execute the rest of the try block after an exception was caught and the except block was executed.

Example:

```
[...]
try:
 do.this()
 do.that()
 [...]
except:
 foo.bar()
[...]
```

`do.this()` raise an exception managed by `foo.bar()`, then I would like to execute the code from `do.that()`. I know that there is not a GOTO statement, but maybe some kind of hack or workaround!

Thanks!

Comment: This indicates that something is wrong with your design. If `do.that` can operate even when `do.this` has raised an exception, then they should not be in the same try-except-block. You would have to provide information on what the functions are actually doing so we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 5):

A `try... except...` block catches *one* exception. That's what it's for. It executes the code inside the try, and if an exception is raised, handles it in the except. You can't raise multiple exceptions inside the try.

This is deliberate: the point of the construction is that you need **explicitly** to handle the exceptions that occur. Returning to the end of the `try` violates this, because then the `except` statement handles more than one thing.

You should do:

```
try:
    do.this()
except FailError:
    clean.up()

try:
    do.that()
except FailError:
    clean.up()
```

so that any exception you raise is handled explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Use a finally block?  Am I missing something?

```
   [...] 
    try: 
     do.this() 
    except: 
     foo.bar() 
    [...] 
    finally:
     do.that()
     [...]
```

Comment: I wasn't clear in my question. Actually the exception can be raised from this() or that() or wherever, it doesn't care, but the the point is to "return" in some way to the try block. "Return" or execute in some manner the code in the try block after the exception

Answer (score 1):

If you always need to execute `foo.bar()` why not just move it after the try/except block? Or maybe even to a `finally:` block.

Comment: I don't need to execute always foo.bar(). That was just an example. What I'm trying to do is to return to the try: block after the execution of an except: block

Comment: @Niko P, you cannot return to the `try` block if an exception is raised. But you *can* restructure your code so that you don't need to.

Comment: I know that I cannot return to the try block. But supposing that I am  able to fix do.this() (or any other operation within that try block) at runtime, how can I resume the execution? Only splitting every single call in a try/execute block?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to write a code in such a way that you can re-execute it all when the error condition has been solved, e.g.:

```
while 1:
   try:
      complex_operation()
   except X:
      solve_problem()
      continue
   break
```

Comment: This way re-run all the try: block. I would like to re-start the execution from the next instruction of the failing one.

Comment: That's why I said "write the code in such a way that you can re-execute it all", e.g. code that doesn't need to reacquire resources, things like that. Well, was just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

```
fcts = [do.this, do.that]
for fct in fcts:
    try:
        fct()
    except:
        foo.bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two try blocks, one for each statement in your current try block.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't scale up well, but for smaller blocks of code you could use a classic finite-state-machine:

```
states = [do.this, do.that]
state = 0
while state < len(states):
    try:
        states[state]()
    except:
        foo.bar()
    state += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative. Handle the error condition with a callback, so that after fixing the problem you can continue. The callback would basically contain exactly the same code you would put in the `except` block.

As a silly example, let's say that the exception you want to handle is a missing file, and that you have a way to deal with that problem (a default file or whatever). `fileRetriever` is the callback that knows how to deal with the problem. Then you would write:

```
def myOp(fileRetriever):

    f = acquireFile()
    if not f:
        f = fileRetriever()

    # continue with your stuff...

    f2 = acquireAnotherFile()
    if not f2:
        f2 = fileRetriever()

    # more stuff...


myOp(magicalCallback)
```

Note: I've never seen this design used in practice, but in specific situations I guess it might be usable.